# Issue on Constructor and List init

Tags: python, constructor

i have a strange behavior with Python Constructor and List initialization. Does anyone, can explain me why we have Children from ParentIssue1 on ParentIssue 2 ? Thank you very much.
I try with Python 3.7 and Python 3.9 releases.

```py
class Child():
    def __init__(self, id: int):
        self.id = id

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__} {self.id}"

# Constructor with "issue"
class ParentIssue():
    def __init__(self,
            name: str = "",
            children = []):
        # Variable Redis
        self.name     = name
        self.children = children

# Constructor without
class Parent():
    def __init__(self,
            name: str = "",
            children = []):
        # Variable Redis
        self.name       = name
        self.children   = children if children else []

pf1 = ParentIssue(name="ParentIssue1")
pf1.children.append(Child(id=1))
pf1.children.append(Child(id=2))
print(pf1.name, pf1.children)
pf2 = ParentIssue(name="ParentIssue2")
pf2.children.append(Child(id=3))
pf2.children.append(Child(id=4))
print(pf2.name, pf2.children)

p1 = Parent(name="Parent1")
p1.children.append(Child(id=1))
p1.children.append(Child(id=2))
print(p1.name, p1.children)
p2 = Parent(name="Parent2")
p2.children.append(Child(id=3))
p2.children.append(Child(id=4))
print(p2.name, p2.children)
```

Output:

```sh
ParentIssue1 [Child 1, Child 2]
ParentIssue2 [Child 1, Child 2, Child 3, Child 4]
Parent1 [Child 1, Child 2]
Parent2 [Child 3, Child 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

To read about: "mutable default arguments".

Tl;dr: When you do default argument with mutable value, it actually uses that one list, not empty list for each  new one. That's because **default value is made at function creation**, not with each execution.

When you do `children if children else []` you actually dump the default `children` value because it's falsy, and then you make a new list.

The default mutable value is also why a lot of functions that would take optional iterable have None as default value and assign empty collection inside. They basically do what your "without issue" Parent looks like but with None. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I understand now my issue. 
Maybe another question: I learned "Object" development with C++ language and takes the habit to have a default and overloads Constructors. How did you recommend construction of them in Python ? I try to use classmethod but i am not fully convince by that solution.

Comment: Class methods are the correct solution! :) Class methods are what static methods are in other languages. (Some history: Creator of python said that his "static methods" were supposed to be that but he didn't know how to do that then, so he later did it correctly using class methods but it was too late to remove staticmethod.) Class methods, because they take cls as parameter, upon inheritance will give you correct type, rather than be stuck with parent type (which would happen if you used class name directly)

Comment: Btw, if you have discord account or don't mind creating one, you might want to check out Python Discord (pydis.com for their webpage). It's more of discussion-based help (with beginner-friendly approach), while SO is Q&A format. :)